How to Limit Scrollable Range on xAxis in LightningChartJS
I'm using LightningchartJS and have encountered an issue with the xAxis zoom functionality in a chart. Specifically, I'm referring to the behavior observed in this live demo:
Currently, users can zoom in and out on the xAxis by scrolling the mouse wheel, as demonstrated in the screenshots below:


This unrestricted zooming is not ideal for my use case. I would like to restrict the zoom range on the xAxis such that users can only zoom between the values of -0.5 and 1.5. How can I configure the xAxis properties or use event handlers to achieve this limited zooming capability?
Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Typed "restrict" into developer documentation search box. Received "restricting axis interval".
Would kindly recommend using developer documentation before asking questions online for improved efficiency.


I searched for limit scrolling

yAxis.setIntervalRestrictions is not a function :(

not working , throws an error :(

is it supportend on version 4.2.1 ?
